# jQuery Alternative Div Elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Can someone please help me understand the jQuery code and how it relates to my HTML. The links are going through and hiding all the divs, however I can't figure out why the div isn't showing when it's link is clicked.

HTML:

```
<section class="meet-the-team pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="conor-link" data-target="conor">Link 1</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="kyle-link" data-target="kyle">Link 2</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tracey-link" data-target="tracey">Link 3</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="frank-link" data-target="frank">Link 4</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="rosie-link" data-target="rosie">Link 5</a>
        <div class="meet-the-team-info">
          <div class="conor-div">
            <h1>Conor</h1>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="alternatetext" style="width:100px;">
            <p>Hello Hello Hello</p>
          </div>
          <div class="kyle-div">I'm div2</div>
          <div class="tracey-div">I'm div3</div>
          <div class="frank-div">I'm div4</div>
          <div class="rosie-div">I'm div5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {

    $(".kyle-div, .tracey-div, .frank-div, .rosie-div").hide();

    $("a").bind("click", function () {
       $(".conor-div, .kyle-div, .tracey-div, .frank-div, .rosie-div").hide();
       var target = $(this).data("target");
       $("."+target).toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: What old version of jQuery are you using since you are using bind()?

Comment: You class name is `kyle-div` but you are selecting it by `.kyle` since the target is `data-target="kyle"` Since there is no elements with the class of kyle, nothing is shown....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change one line of your jQuery.

```js
$(function () {

    $(".kyle-div, .tracey-div, .frank-div, .rosie-div").hide();

    $("a").bind("click", function () {
       $(".conor-div, .kyle-div, .tracey-div, .frank-div, .rosie-div").hide();
       var target = $(this).data("target");
       $("."+target+"-div").show() //added "-div" and changed toggle to show
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="meet-the-team pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="conor-link" data-target="conor">Link 1</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="kyle-link" data-target="kyle">Link 2</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="tracey-link" data-target="tracey">Link 3</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="frank-link" data-target="frank">Link 4</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="rosie-link" data-target="rosie">Link 5</a>
        <div class="meet-the-team-info">
          <div class="conor-div">
            <h1>Conor</h1>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="alternatetext" style="width:100px;">
            <p>Hello Hello Hello</p>
          </div>
          <div class="kyle-div">I'm div2</div>
          <div class="tracey-div">I'm div3</div>
          <div class="frank-div">I'm div4</div>
          <div class="rosie-div">I'm div5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: why make a fiddle when stackoverflow has the ability with snipplets?

Comment: Good point.  I didn't realize how easy it was to use stackoverflow's ability.  I think that I prefer it over jsfiddle now.

Answer (score 1):

@natels's solution works and deserves to be the accepted answer. But even his solution can be shortened a little bit:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    $(".meet-the-team-info div:visible").hide(); // first hide all visible team divs,
    $("."+this.dataset.target+"-div").show();    // then show the chosen one
  }).eq(0).click(); // emulate a click on the first link (index=0)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="meet-the-team pt-5 pb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <a href="#" class="conor-link" data-target="conor">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="kyle-link" data-target="kyle">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="tracey-link" data-target="tracey">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="frank-link" data-target="frank">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="gwen-link" data-target="gwen">Link 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="rosie-link" data-target="rosie">Link 6</a>
        <div class="meet-the-team-info">
          <div class="conor-div">
            <h1>I'm Conor</h1>
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="alternatetext" style="width:100px;">
            <p>Hello Hello Hello</p>
          </div>
          <div class="kyle-div">I'm Kyle</div>
          <div class="tracey-div">I'm Tracey</div>
          <div class="frank-div">I'm Frank</div>
          <div class="gwen-div">I'm Gwen</div>
          <div class="rosie-div">I'm Rosie</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

The code in this snippet does not need to be adjusted if more divs are to be included in the page. The individual class names do not occur in the code any more.

Comment: Thanks for the credit, and I like your shortened version.  Hard for people like me to read, but very smart!

Answer (score 0):

i think you have an extra hide() there. The first hide(), hides all the divs on page load. But then on click you say "hide" and "toggle". They're canceling each other or doing something unexpected. Try just toggle(). And also you're missing the "div" part in your selector.

```
$(function () {

$(".kyle-div, .tracey-div, .frank-div, .rosie-div").hide();

$("a").bind("click", function () {
  // $(".conor-div, .kyle-div, .tracey-div, .frank-div, .rosie-div").hide();
   var target = $(this).data("target");
   $("."+target+"-div").toggle();
});
```

});

Comment: I did not downvote, I can gladly downvote it now if you would like. Questions that are basically typos, people tend to downvote answers. ANd my comment under the question pointed out the problem before you answered. ;)

Comment: I was typing the answer when you answered. Sorry if I mistook you for the downvoter.